# Grabbing/rearranging data from SQL for table

Tags: sql

I have data in sql that looks like so:

```
Month  PersonID  Level 
 01       102      2
 01       506      1
 02       617      3
 02       506      1
 03       297      2
```

And I need to query this data to receive it for use in a table that would look like this

```
         Jan  Feb  March ...etc
Level 1
Level 2
Level 3
```

with the values being how many people are in each level each month.

I'm a complete noob with SQL so any help and relevant links to explain answers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you use?

Comment: I'm using SQLServer 2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 'Level ' + CAST("Level" AS VARCHAR(2)),
    SUM(CASE Month WHEN '01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jan,
    SUM(CASE Month WHEN '02' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Feb,
    SUM(CASE Month WHEN '03' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Mar,
    ...

FROM myTable
GROUP BY "Level"
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/31518/1)

This is basically a poor man's pivot table, which should work on most RDBMS. What it does is use a SUM with a CASE to achieve a count-if for each month. That is, for January, the value for each row will be 1 if `Month` = '01', or 0 otherwise. Summing these values gets the total count of all "January" rows in your table.

The `GROUP BY Level` clause tells the engine to produce one result row for each distinct value in `Level`, thus separating your data by the different levels.

---

Since you are using SQL Server 2005, which supports [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), you can simply do:

```
SELECT 'Level ' + CAST("Level" AS VARCHAR(2)), 
    [01] AS [Jan], [02] AS [Feb], [03] AS [Mar], ...
FROM myTable
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(PersonId)
    FOR Month IN ([01], [02], [03], ...)
) x
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/31518/4)

Comment: Good, but you don't need the COALESCE's in the first example.

Comment: FYI, the first approach is called a "Cross-Tab Query".

Comment: @RBarryYoung You're right, there's always going to be a row there...not sure what I was on. :)

Comment: Well that's pretty damn awesome of you. Another task if your up for it? Using the same data as before is it possible to get the data out into 3 columns "Total, Month, Level". You nailed the previous answer but I realised that I'm meant to be putting this into a pivot table in excel and with the data how it was there isn't really much for the pivot table to do. Also it would be great know different ways of doing things for the future.

Comment: @EvilWeebl That one's the easy one: `SELECT COUNT(1) AS Total, Month, Level FROM myTable GROUP BY Month, Level`

Comment: @Ic Your a hero thanks! I really need to pick up a book on this stuff. Although..and I know I'm being cheeky going for a third question, I don't need this but it's out of pure interest, as I don't have data for some months or some levels then then the returned data doesn't create rows for them. Is there a way to create rows in the output for months and levels even if they have no rows in the database?

Comment: @EvilWeebl Yes I suggest picking up a book as it'll help you learn and really be a good reference. As for your question that one's actually pretty hard and needs a bit of explanation. Why don't you [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT 'Level' + CAST(level as varchar), [January], [February], [March]
FROM (SELECT DATENAME(month, '2013'+Month+'01') Month, PersonID, Level FROM Tbl) T
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(PersonID) FOR Month IN ([January], [February], [March])

) A
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/40390/14)**